# SetXp command does only work on the person who uses the command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

SetXp command does only work on the person who uses the command and if i wanna give anyone else xp it does not work. I hope someone know what i need to do.
Thanks

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const Levels = require('discord-xp')

Levels.setURL("")

bot.login('')

bot.on("ready!", bot => {
    console.log('Bot is Online!')
})

bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const prefix = '+';

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    var randomXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1; //Random amont of XP until the number you want + 1
    const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXp);
    if (hasLeveledUp) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`You leveled up to ${user.level}! Keep it going!`);
    }
    
    if(command === "setxp" || command === "setXp") {
        const member = await message.mentions.members.first(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]); // setxp @user
        const amount = args[1]; // setxp @user 100
        Levels.setXp(message.member.id, message.guild.id, amount);
        
        
        message.channel.send(`here your xp my friend`)
    
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why your code doesn't work.

1. You don't get the `member` correctly

When you execute `message.mentions.members.first()` you access the collection that is `message.mentions.members`, so all mentions of guild members in a given message. That can be one but it can also be more then that which is where `first()` comes into play. As you may have guessed it returns the first item in the given collection. That also means you don't need to pass any arguments to it.

TL;DR: drop the argument from `message.mentions.members.first()`.

2. You don't give the XP to the correct person *Note: This is the real issue*

In your code you pass `message.member.id` to the `setXp` function. That is always the person who sends the message. So to fix this you need to actually pass `member` from 1. to the function.

```
Levels.setXp(member.id, message.guild.id, amount);
```

*Some additional thoughts:*

- you can drop `|| command === "setXp` because you convert the command to lowercase in the beginning.
- if you plan to have more then 1 command you might wanna think about using a command handler. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64289650/typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-execute-of-undefined-when-trying-to-execute/64294025#64294025) for more details.
- it's `here are your xp my friend` or `here're your xp my friend`